# List<order>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core

I am actually facing a strange problem. I am actually trying to return list of data by find specific id. Everything should work but I don't understand why I am facing this annoying error. Here is my code below.

`order.cs`:

```cs
public class order
{
    public int  Id { get; set; }

    public int? Seid { get; set; }
    public AppUser Seuser { get; set; }

    public int? Reid { get; set; }
    public AppUser Reuser { get; set; }

    public string Status  { get; set; } 
}
```

Controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task <ActionResult<IEnumerable<order>>>GetOrder()
{
    var currentuserid = int.Parse(User.GetUserId());
    var r = await _orderRepository.GetOrders(currentuserid);
    if(r!=null)
    {
        return  Ok(r); 
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

orderRepository:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<order>> GetOrders(int id)
{
   return await _context.Orders.Where(x => x.Seid == id).ToList(); //here mainly found error when added await
}
```

Error:

> `List<order>` does not contain a definition for `GetAwaiter` and no
> accessible extension method `GetAwaiter` accepting a first argument of
> type `List<order>` could be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly reference?) [API]csharp(CS1061)

[image]

When I remove `await` to this line of code:- `return await _context.Orders.Where(x => x.Seid == id).ToList();` then error gone. But when I run my application I found a different error just for this `await` case. I am an absolute beginner. How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you keep `await` and remove `.ToList()`?

Comment: Side note, a good thing to research is the difference between Lists, IEnumerables, and IQueryables.

Comment: @gunr2171 same error after keep await and remove .Tolist()

Comment: `ToList` -> `ToListAsync`?

Comment: New error :- ```IQueryable<order>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no accessible extension method 'ToListAsync'```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use [`IAsyncEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1?view=net-6.0) interface that provides asynchronous iteration over values of a specified type:

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<List<order>> GetOrders(int id)
{
    yield return await _context.Orders.Where(x => x.Seid == id).ToListAsync<order>();
}
```

See description of the [Compiler Error CS1983](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1983)

Comment: Found this error now:- ```IQueryable<order>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no accessible extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<order>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)```

Comment: @PeterParker: Check that you have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` in your file.

Comment: `IAsyncEnumerable` is not a type of `Task<T>`. Both are unrelated [awaitable expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#11882-awaitable-expressions).

Comment: Furthermore, you should be streaming the orders whilst using `IAsyncEnumerable`. If you want to run the query and return a List, `Task` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can only `await` objects that define `GetAwaiter()`.
Try removing the `await`, or using [`ToListAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

As a side note, if your implementation doesn't explicitly require a `List`, I'd suggest just returning an IEnumerable:

```csharp
public async Task<IEnumerable<order>> GetOrders(int id)
 {
   return _context.Orders.Where(x => x.Seid == id);
 }
```

If you are required to return a `List`, I'd suggest changing the method signature to reflect that you'll always return a `List`:

```
public async Task<List<order>> GetOrders(int id)
 {
   return _context.Orders.Where(x => x.Seid == id).ToListAsync();
 }
```

Comment: No it's not working!

Comment: In what way is it not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Thanks pal. I appriciate your help.